# Passing parameters to function with variable or modifying during passing

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

While passing parameter to function, there are two ways to pass and i'm not sure about which one is better?

First one is:

```
const foo = (bar) => bar;

number = 3.4567;
foo(number.toFixed(2));
```

Second one is:

```
const foo = (bar) => bar;

number = 3.4567;
fixedNumber = number.toFixed(2);
foo(fixedNumber);
```

Comment: You can store the result of any expression in a variable and use the variable instead. I wouldn't call this "a different way" though, and one isn't better than the other. It all depends on what you need. If you need the result elsewhere then of course store it in a variable first. If it's not needed elsewhere then there is no need to store it in a variable.

Comment: The first option is best if you don't need to store the variable and use it first

Comment: You tagged the question with "performance". While in theory more operations are involved if you keep an extra variable, engines are likely optimizing this, and any performance difference will not be measurable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically the same but in the second one you define a new variable for `fixedNumber`, thus making your code more readable for other developers.

Comment: I disagree with this, assuming this is meant as a blanket statement. It's only more readable if the variable name is descriptive and simple. If it's not, I have to go and find the definition of the variable to see which value it actually contains. In other words, seeing something like `sumOfXAndY` is not necessarily more readable than `x + y`.

Comment: Agreed. I almost always use variables (and never comments) to describe my code, but, for this example, the code is short enough and self-explanatory so a descriptive variable isn't necessery.